# Javascript Get value from JSON in loop

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have the following issue, i want to get all the polyline.points data from json:

```
"legs" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "115 km",
              "value" : 115373
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "1 hour 14 mins",
              "value" : 4433
           },
           "duration_in_traffic" : {
              "text" : "1 hour 10 mins",
              "value" : 4205
           },
           "end_address" : "Ermelo, Netherlands",
           "end_location" : {
              "lat" : 52.2986269,
              "lng" : 5.629653999999999
           },
           "start_address" : "Zwijndrecht, Netherlands",
           "start_location" : {
              "lat" : 51.8108387,
              "lng" : 4.6268639
           },
           "steps" : [
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "45 m",
                    "value" : 45
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "1 min",
                    "value" : 9
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 51.81113269999999,
                    "lng" : 4.627318
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Head \u003cb\u003enortheast\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eKorenbloemstraat\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eLeeuwenbekstraat\u003c/b\u003e",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "whf{H{tf[y@{A"
                 },
```

in this json there are multiple polyline.points keys.
I have the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
//console.log(body.routes[0].legs[0].steps[0].polyline.points);
    var keys = [];
    for(var i = 0;i<body.routes[0].legs[0].steps.length;i++)
    {
    Object.keys(body.routes[0].legs[0].steps[i]).forEach(function(value){
    if(value == 'polyline') {
      Object.keys(value).forEach(function(value){
        console.log(value);


    }
});
```

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: you can iterate over `for (var key in body.routes[0].legs[0].steps[i]){console.log(key)}`

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I want all the values from "points" comma seperated. In this example there is 1 polyline : whf{H{tf[y@{A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`legs` is a property of an object but you havent said if there is just one object at that level or ifs its part of an array but shouldnt be too hard to modify if it is.

You can use reduce to turn your `legs.steps` arrays into one big array, then map over that to extract the `polyline.points`.

This way if you have multiple elements in the `legs` array or the `steps` array it will just work. Just be aware if `polyline` is undefined it will throw an exception so you will need to add some error checking of some form.

```
var data = data.legs.reduce((prev, cur) => {
    prev.push(...cur.steps);

    return prev;
  }, [])
  .map(x => x.polyline.points);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0x3wbq4/1/)

[Reduce Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

[Map docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

---

EDIT: Modified as per the OPs comments:

This [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0x3wbq4/2/) will just blindly expect to receive an object and get the first `routes` object from it.

This second [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0x3wbq4/4/) will flatten the `routes` and `steps` into one big array of coordinates. I know you said you didn't need to but it seemed like a fun challenge :)

FYI its ES6 compliant so IE is of the cards.

Comment: Can't get this to work in my javascript... this is the full json output: http://pastebin.com/3bvG5Yxq

Comment: @MichaelSmits could there be multiple objects in the `routes` array? If so do you need to extract the `points` nested in these too? This is what i meant in my first paragraph. Shouldn't be too difficult, ill update my answer if you do. Either way please define `how` its not working.

Comment: No there won't be multiple object in the routes array. Sorry, i'm new to javascript! Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hey your 'value' variable contains (key, value) pair. so use value['polyline'] to get your data.

Comment: When i use that variable, i get this response: { decode: [Function],
  encode: [Function],
  fromGeoJSON: [Function],
  toGeoJSON: [Function] }